# Sample node.js app not running on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I have never used Node.js before, but I am just trying to run a sample application on Heroku. The app that I am running is

https://github.com/heroku-examples/geosockets

<strike>I may be wrong, since I am not familiar with node.js, but I think the [Procfile](https://github.com/heroku-examples/geosockets/blob/master/Procfile) may be incorrect:</strike>

```
web: coffee index.coffee
redis-dev: redis-server
grunt-dev: grunt watch
```

When I try to run either <strike>`redis-server`</strike> or `grunt watch` at my terminal, <strike>they do</strike> it does not work. I've tried running `foreman start` as well.

My question is what do I need to do to get this application running locally? How do I run the <strike>redis server and</strike> the grunt process?

---

**EDIT**- Once I installed redis via the Ubuntu package manager, I can now run `redis-server` *locally* from the command line. However, on Heroku when I try to start a redis worker dyno it says this in the logs.

```
2013-11-13T06:55:53.219721+00:00 heroku[redisdev.1]: Starting process with command `redis-server`
2013-11-13T06:55:53.777822+00:00 app[redisdev.1]: bash: redis-server: command not found
2013-11-13T06:55:54.830721+00:00 heroku[redisdev.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-11-13T06:55:54.843111+00:00 heroku[redisdev.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Similarly, when I try to start a grunt worker on Heroku I get a similar message in the logs

```
2013-11-13T07:24:03.612764+00:00 heroku[gruntdev.1]: Starting process with command `grunt watch`
2013-11-13T07:24:04.215564+00:00 app[gruntdev.1]: bash: grunt: command not found
2013-11-13T07:24:05.416066+00:00 heroku[gruntdev.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-11-13T07:24:05.427289+00:00 heroku[gruntdev.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

How do I configure my application to run these on Heroku?

Comment: have you done an `npm install` first of all? what is your error message?

Comment: yes, I did an `npm install` initially. Now, when I type it again I see this message 

    `npm WARN package.json grunt-casper@0.1.3 No repository field.` <newline> 
    `npm WARN package.json hiredis@0.1.15 No repository field.`

Comment: Those are acceptable as many modules don't have repositories defined. what happens when you run `coffee index.coffee`?

Comment: When I run `coffee index.coffee` it seems like the server starts, because no new terminal prompt appears. Then, if I go to localhost:5000 in my browser, I see the app running and this appears back in the terminal screen: `{ uuid: '44039d31-0fab-401e-b78d-f5de481b84d1',
  url: 'https://geosockets.herokuapp.com/',
  latitude: <my_lat>,
  longitude: <my_long> }` (with my actual latitude and longitude)

Comment: is the code still configured to work with geosockets.herokuapp.com rather than my herokuapp URL?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after further investigation, I can run it ***locally*** now. I assumed that the `npm install` command had set up everything I needed but that was not the case.

First, I installed redis-server via the ubuntu package manager

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

Then I found that I needed to install the [Grunt command line interface](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started):

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

However, I still have not been able to get these to run on Heroku

Comment: you probably need to add on some services to your heroku instance https://addons.heroku.com/?q=redis and grunt needs this https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt